# How to remove file from git repo before push?

Tags: git

I have added new files, commited and pushed to repo. Now I added new, better classes for this purpose and I want to delete this files (`Content.java`), so that git doesn't follw this file anymore. How to achieve this? remove Content.java from project and then push?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(This question would be answered very early into any git tutorial.)  You can stage the removal of that file with:

```
git rm Content.java
```

... which also removes it from your working tree.  Then you should create a commit:

```
git commit
```

... and push as before.

Comment: we are coming here to get answers without reading the annoying manuals... so, thx anyway :D

Comment: @jebbie: well, I hope it helped then!

Comment: unfortunately, no.. i'm still completely stuck in my use-case but i will just going to create a new question about it..

Comment: maybe you can help me out? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998138/remove-a-file-from-git-which-is-not-pushed-yet-but-also-not-in-latest-commit