# Remove a file from git which is not pushed yet but also not in latest commit?

Tags: git

I've found this wonderful help-page of git:

https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/

and both approaches are *not* working for me... i think because the big-file i trying to get rid of is not in the latest commit and i was not able to push yet... but in the latest state, i already removed the file.. and this delete is also not pushed yet..

so this is what it looks like:

[image]

- in the selected revision i accidently added the big-stupid .mov file
- two commits later i've removed it

and as you can see i already tried out a thing:

- i switched back to the revision just after i've added the file "git checkout blabla"
- i deleted the file "git rm /assets/video/landed.mov"
- i made a new commit "git commit -m 'removed landed.mov"
- i switched back to master -> he's warning me that i will loose my change from this commit, why not creating a new branch? -> so i created new branch "fixing-movie"
- and finally i re-integrated the branch into master, hoping it will fix "somehow" my large file issue

and yes.. obviously it fixed nothing - because he still wants to push the problematic commit first before he gets into all my deletions of this file again...

any help welcome, extremely welcome! because the only thing left in my mind is - creating a new repo.. loosing all commits.. and hacking in all the changes manually again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an interactive rebase and 'fix-up' the commit that removed the unwanted file into the commit in which you added it. This will essentially leave the original commit as though the file was never added.

From the command line (you need to commit/stash any changes):

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

You'll be presented with a text editor in which you can manipulate the commits you made, from top to bottom. Move the *"removed..."* commit up so that it comes directly after the _"MOJ-1120..." commit. Change the `pick` to `fixup`, save the file and exit.

If this doesn't do what you want, you can use the git reflog to go back to where you were beforehand. You may like to write down the current SHA before doing this to make it easier.

Comment: omg i guess it worked now, but i had to take two attempts until he made what i wanted.. fortunately i had two commits doing the exact same thing in this little history (deleting the god damn .mov file) - now it has gone and i can push again.. YAY

Comment: @jebbie, glad to hear it worked for you. Interactive rebasing is pretty powerful and not that complicated really.