# Create remote repository from existed folder

Tags: git, version-control

I have a Visual Studio solution in my local folder. I already have `.gitignore` for it. Now I am looking for some way how to push it to remote git server considering `.gitignore' file.

I am already know how `init` repository in my local folder and how to push it to git folder. But I need some solution how to push only that files which is not on `.gitignore'.

Is any way to do it exists?

Answer (score 0):

git will only consider the files which are not present in `.gitignore`, unless you have already committed the file.

If you have already done a commit then you can do

```
git rm -r --cached <file_name>
```

which will will stop tracking the files present inside `.gitignore`.

You will have to create a bare repository on the remote:

```
git init --bare
```

For setting the remote for the local repository:

```
git remote add origin REMOTE_URL
```

Push all your local changes:

```
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you commit, Git won't show you any files which match patterns in `.gitignore`. So simply pushing should already do what you want (since the files shouldn't be in the repo).

If you accidentally (or deliberately) committed files which Git normally ignores, then there is no way to push "everything else." Git creates secure checksums for commits so if you'd omit some parts, the checksums wouldn't match and the remote server would reject the push.

The easiest solution in this case is to delete the files locally and commit this change. The files will still be visible and reachable through the history (i.e. when you go back, the files will appear) but for a new checkout, they will be gone.

If you really need to delete the file and you haven't pushed, yet, see this question how to edit the local history: [Remove a file from git which is not pushed yet but also not in latest commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998138/remove-a-file-from-git-which-is-not-pushed-yet-but-also-not-in-latest-commit)